# Makefile for cuda code

Tags: cuda, makefile

Ok, here I have a problem with my makefile .
I have the files MatMulCpu.cu, MatMulGPU.cu, MatMulGPU_ms.cu 
I want to compile them and compile the file MatMul.cu, which needs those three files .
Here is my makefile...

```
CC=nvcc
EXEC=MatMul

all: $(EXEC)
MatMul: MatMulGPU_ms.o MatMulCPU.o MatMulGPU.o
$(CC) -o MatMul MatMulCPU.o MatMulGPU.o MatMulGPU_ms.o

MatMulCPU.o: MatMulCPU.cu
$(CC) -o MatMulCPU.o MatMulCPU.cu

MatMulCPU.o: MatMulGPU.cu
$(CC) -o MatMulGPU.o MatMulGPU.cu

MatMulCPU.o: MatMulGPU_ms.cu
$(CC) -o MatMulGPU_ms.o MatMulGPU_ms.cu

clean:
rm -rf *.o

mrproper: clean
rm -rf MatMul
```

And I have those warnings and errors :

```
makefile:12: warning: overriding commands for target `MatMulCPU.o'
makefile:9: warning: ignoring old commands for target `MatMulCPU.o'
makefile:15: warning: overriding commands for target `MatMulCPU.o'
makefile:12: warning: ignoring old commands for target `MatMulCPU.o'
make: *** No rule to make target `MatMulGPU.cu', needed by `MatMulCPU.o'.  Stop.
```

Don't know what to solve it . Searched several makefiles on the internet, but it couldn't help me :/

EDIT : Ok thanks now I modified the makefile, it seems to be ok

```
CC=nvcc
EXEC=MatMul

all: $(EXEC)
MatMul: MatMulGPU_ms.o MatMulCPU.o MatMulGPU2.o
$(CC) -o MatMul MatMulCPU.o MatMulGPU2.o MatMulGPU_ms.o

MatMulCPU.o: MatMulCPU.cu
$(CC) -o MatMulCPU.o MatMulCPU.cu

MatMulGPU2.o: MatMulGPU2.cu
$(CC) -o MatMulGPU2.o MatMulGPU2.cu

MatMulGPU_ms.o: MatMulGPU_ms.cu
$(CC) -o MatMulGPU_ms.o MatMulGPU_ms.cu

clean:
rm -rf *.o

mrproper: clean
rm -rf MatMul
```

But now I have others errors...

```
MatMulGPU.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
[...manythings_here_that_shows_all_the_multiple_definitions...]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:/build/buildd/eglibc-2.19/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:118: first defined here
```

I have the same for some stuff, like _fini, IO_stdin_used, _data_start, _dso_handle ... I don't know what it is !

Is this due to the make file or to the code ?

It seems to say that also other stuff, like main functions or Matrix definitions that are said to be more than one time defined...but the definitions aren't in the same file ! For example, I have a Matrix definition in MatMulCPU.cu and MatMulGPU2.cu, so why is it a problem ....? :/

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying the same target (`MatMulCPU.o`) multiple times.  There is no need to do this.   But you should have a target for each object (.o) that will be built.

Try this:

```
CC=nvcc
EXEC=MatMul

all: $(EXEC)
MatMul: MatMulGPU_ms.o MatMulCPU.o MatMulGPU.o
      $(CC) -o MatMul MatMulCPU.o MatMulGPU.o MatMulGPU_ms.o

MatMulCPU.o: MatMulCPU.cu
      $(CC) -c -o MatMulCPU.o MatMulCPU.cu

MatMulGPU.o: MatMulGPU.cu
      $(CC) -c -o MatMulGPU.o MatMulGPU.cu

MatMulGPU_ms.o: MatMulGPU_ms.cu
      $(CC) -c -o MatMulGPU_ms.o MatMulGPU_ms.cu

clean:
      rm -rf *.o

mrproper: clean
      rm -rf MatMul
```

Comment: Ok now I've seen my failures ;) thanks ! but now I have other errors . I edited the first post in order to show the new version of makefile and than the errors ... Can somebody help me?

Comment: I've modified my answer.  Try adding the `-c` switches to each of the `.o` targets, as I did in my answer.  Although you haven't shown your code, with that change I was able to use the makefile to build a simple example like [this](http://pastebin.com/xQTaFJ71).  If that doesn't fix it, then the problem has to do with how your code is structured, and you haven't shown your code.  In that case, I would suggest posting a new question.